# if my iOS app freezes the entire phone, is this considered a bug in the OS itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, avplayer, freeze

I am working on an iOS app where I am using AVPlayer to play different mp4 videos. Most of the times it works fine. except sometimes my app completely freezes the phone. I haven't been able to catch it at what place this happens but I think it usually happens right after this line. I verified this by placing a bunch of NSLog where I print the `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` :

```
mylayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:myplayer];
```

The freeze happens for a few seconds (sometimes much longer).

Even if I press home button or lock button, the phone is unresponsive.
I have to end up pressing the lock button for about 6-10 seconds which hard restarts the entire phone.

Note that the CPU and memory usage doesn't spike during this.

I understand my code might be buggy and all but shouldn't the OS be intelligent enough to not let a single app completely freeze the entire phone? Would this be considered an OS bug? If so, I might log a DTS with Apple.

---

****EDIT: added code****

**Note the comment which says "// this is the line which freezes"**

```
dispatch_queue_t LOADQUEUE = dispatch_queue_create("com.yolo.LOADQUEUE", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        dispatch_async(LOADQUEUE, ^{
            AVURLAsset *avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];


            NSLog(@"current time 4: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
            if ([avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] && [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count>0) {
                NSLog(@"current time 4.5: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                CGSize size = [[[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
                NSLog(@"current time 5: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                CGRect r = self.topHeader.frame;
                r.size.height=((size.height*self.view.frame.size.width)/size.width)+self.topheaderBottomView.frame.size.height+self.topheadertopview.frame.size.height+self.itemTitle.frame.size.height;
                howMuchToScrollToShowCommentButton=r.size.height;

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                    self.topHeader.frame=r;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{

                        [self.mytableview setTableHeaderView:self.topHeader];

                    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        NSArray *keys = @[@"playable"];
                        NSLog(@"current time 6: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                        [avAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                NSLog(@"current time 7: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                                AVPlayerItem *newItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];
                                if (!myplayer) {
                                    myplayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:newItem];
                                } else {
                                    [myplayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newItem];
                                }
                                NSLog(@"current time 7.5: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                                [myplayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
                                [myplayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                           object:[myplayer currentItem]];
                                myplayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
                                NSLog(@"current time 7.6: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                                mylayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:myplayer]; // this is the line which freezes
                                NSLog(@"current time 7.7: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);


                                [playerView.layer addSublayer:mylayer];
                                mylayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
                                [mylayer setFrame:playerView.bounds];
                                [myplayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
                                NSLog(@"current time 8: %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
                            });
                        }];


                    }];
                });
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ITEM doesn't exist");
            }
        });
```

**Output:
Note the 21 second break between time 7.6 and 7.7 :**

```
2016-06-04 01:27:20.853 XYZ[402:49072] current time 7: 1465018040.853897
2016-06-04 01:27:20.875 XYZ[402:49072] current time 7.5: 1465018040.875220
2016-06-04 01:27:20.875 XYZ[402:49072] current time 7.6: 1465018040.875871
2016-06-04 01:27:41.841 XYZ[402:49072] current time 7.7: 1465018061.841419
2016-06-04 01:27:41.841 XYZ[402:49072] current time 8: 1465018061.841863
```

Edit 2:

I paused the app in xcode and looked at what the threads were doing on the left. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be a symptom of debugging and running through XCode.  You're right, normally you should always be able to hit the Home button and exit the application.

Edit your scheme and change from Debug to Release.  Run a build once through Xcode.  Kill the app, then Launch it without Xcode from the Home screen of the device.

Comment: I have noticed my app freeze the OS even when not in debug mode and not connected to my mac. this especially seems to happen when my internet is slow (when I am on train and my network is shitty)

Comment: If you could update your question and include more code related to the action that causes the problem we might be able to help.  It sounds like something on the main thread is locking everything up.

Comment: thanks for your help, I just added my code and NSLog output.

Comment: is "mlayer" an @property (atomic, strong) ?  If not, that might help.  This looks like a dead lock of some sort.

Comment: It's defined in the interface as an instance variable. defined as:

AVPlayerLayer *mylayer;

Comment: still same problem even if i change it to a @property

Comment: I added a screenshot of xcode paused when the freeze occurs

Comment: Yea, it's definately a dead lock waiting on something else to finish with the CALayer but obviously never happens.. The only stuff in your code touching the UI is the UIAnimation.. Maybe that has something to do with it.. Try not doing that to test it. edit: first try adding a slight duration instead of "0"

Comment: but the problem comes after the animation is already done because the problem is inside the completion block.